# Use Jquery to Insert PHP content

Tags: php, jquery

I want to use jQuery to include some PHP at a certain point in the page. When jQuery finds the class `#site-index .sitetopic` I want to append the content from a PHP file called images.php.

I presume I can use `include or file_get_contents`

Something like:

```
OnLoad.find('#site-index .sitetopic')
  InsertPHP
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't insert server side code on the client.

By the time Jquery would execute, the server is already done processing the page.

You could however use an iframe that you use jquery to add, or even use jquery's .load function http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: You could, however, use an iframe pointing at the PHP file and insert it there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load and execute **PHP code** on the client side, but you can load the **output** of `images.php`.

I'm not sure if you want to place the output where `#site-index .sitetopic` is, or somewhere else:

```
// loads the output of images.php into the elements with class sitetopic
$('#site-index .sitetopic').load('images.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert server side code on client side - however you could **call** the script `images.php` which would do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's get(or post) function:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

This allows you to send some variables to your server side script wich in turn returns some html or a variable you can use in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you just can't.
And I assume it was for the sake of speed but don't worry, PHP doesn't `include` files with an HTTP request but it fetches them from the HDD, so your page won't load slower.